# SqlDataReader can not be loaded into table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a `SqlDataReader` from a SQL Server command and want I to show in a `DataDridView` with this code:

```
SqlDataReader dr=product.RetriveDetailsOfOneProduct();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);
DataGrid.DataSource = dr;
```

I checked it using breakpoints that my `SqlDataReader` has rows but when loading it into `DataTable`, it is empty (with no rows)

How can I fix this?

And it is function of my DataAccess class where `SqlDataReader` is returned:

```
internal SqlDataReader RetriveDetailsOfOneProduct(product product)
{
     string RetriveQuery = string.Format("SElect person.F_Name as N'Name ',person.L_Name as N'LastName',borrow.Person_Identity as N'Identity',borrow.T_Date as 'Date1', borrow.B_Date as 'Date2' from BorrowTable borrow Inner join PersonTable person on borrow.Product_Name=N'{0}' and person.Person_identity=borrow.Person_Identity ", product.Productname);

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(RetriveQuery, conn);
     // conn.Close();  //if i close the Connection(conn) it runs into error
     return(cmd.ExecuteReader());
}
```

Comment: you need to make sure you bind the data to the DataGrid as well just setting the Source is not good enough

Comment: I would suggest porting the query over to a stored procedure as well.
it will be easier to maintain vs trying to edit dynamic sql in your code. also wrap your SqlCommand Objects around a `using(){}` for auto disposing

Comment: thanks for all of you worked good.i made a mistake with assigning dt to DataGrid,now it works good

Comment: please select one of the answers as the acceptable answer thanks

Comment: both of them are the same and acceptable

Comment: actually they are not the same one has the first error which is the same as the one I have ..the second has to deal with with you refresh and or set the initial viewing of the data in the datagridview..you would need to bind that data..

Comment: @MethodMan: Ok yours is more usefull thanks

Comment: I appreciate that but I would suggest reading up on [msdn datagrid.databind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.databind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and understand why it's needed when you are wanting to rebind data.. thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are setting the data source to the data reader instead of the data table.

```
DataGrid.DataSource = dr;
```

should be

```
DataGrid.DataSource = dt;
DataGrid.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign the datatable, not the datareader...

```
DataGrid.DataSource = dt;
```